# Display Configurable product Highest price by default

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price

I need to show configurable product highest price in frontend.

currently by default magento is loading lowest price.

please help me to solve this issue.

Tried by overriding

> "Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\ConfigurablePriceResolver"

My code :

```
class MaxConfigurablePrice
{
    protected $productRepository;
    protected $productFactory;
    protected $dataObjectHelper;
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $logFilePath = '/var/log/sub_debug.log';
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterfaceFactory $productFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
)
{
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->dataObjectHelper = $dataObjectHelper;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Pricing\SaleableInterface|\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject
 * @param callable $proceed
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Pricing\SaleableInterface $product
 * @return float
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 */
public function aroundResolvePrice($subject, callable $proceed, \Magento\Framework\Pricing\SaleableInterface $product)
{
    // let the before hooks run.
    $returnValue = (float)$proceed($product);

    // and then we'll override with our logic
    $price = null;
    //get parent product id
    $parentId = $product['entity_id'];
    $childObj = $this->getChildProductObj($parentId);
    foreach($childObj as $childProduct){
        $productPrice = $childProduct->getPrice();
        $specialPrice = $childProduct->getData('special_price');

        $price = $price ? max($price, $productPrice) : $productPrice;

        // if the product with the highest price is also
        // the product that has a special price make sure
        // to display the special price (assuming it's valid)
        if ($price == $productPrice && isset($specialPrice)) {
            $now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
            $specialFromDate = $childProduct->getData('special_from_date');
            $specialToDate = $childProduct->getData('special_to_date');

            $this->log('FROM ' . __CLASS__ . '::' . __FUNCTION__ . ' AT LINE ' . __LINE__);
            $this->log('$productPrice: ' . var_export($productPrice, true));
            $this->log('$specialPrice: ' . var_export($specialPrice, true));
            $this->log('$specialFromDate: ' . var_export($specialFromDate, true));
            $this->log('$specialToDate: ' . var_export($specialToDate, true));
            $this->log('$now: ' . var_export($now, true));

            // $this->log('child product debug: ' . print_r($childProduct->debug(), true));


            switch (true) {
                case (isset($specialFromDate) && isset($specialToDate)):
                    if (($now > $specialFromDate) && ($now < $specialToDate)) {
                        $price = $specialPrice;
                    }
                    break;

                case (isset($specialFromDate) && !isset($specialToDate)):
                    if ($now > $specialFromDate) {
                        $price = $specialPrice;
                    }
                    break;

                case (!isset($specialFromDate) && isset($specialToDate)):
                    if ($now < $specialToDate) {
                        $price = $specialPrice;
                    }
                    break;

                case (!isset($specialFromDate) && !isset($specialToDate)):
                    $price = $specialPrice;
                    break;

                default:
                    // do nothing...leave $price as it is
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    $this->log('FROM ' . __CLASS__ . '::' . __FUNCTION__ . ' AT LINE ' . __LINE__);
    $this->log('returned $price: ' . var_export($price, true));

    return $price;
}

public function getProductInfo($id)
{
    //get product obj using api repository...
    if(is_numeric($id)){
        return $this->productRepository->getById($id);
    } else {
        return;
    }
}

public function getChildProductObj($id)
{
    $product = $this->getProductInfo($id);
    // if product with no proper id then return null and exit;
    if(!isset($product)){
        return;
    }

    if ($product->getTypeId() != \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
        return [];
    }

    $storeId = $this->getCurrentStoreId();
    $productTypeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance();
    $productTypeInstance->setStoreFilter($storeId, $product);
    $childrenList = [];

    foreach ($productTypeInstance->getUsedProducts($product) as $child) {
        $attributes = [];
        $isSaleable = $child->isSaleable();

        //get only in stock product info
        if($isSaleable){
            foreach ($child->getAttributes() as $attribute) {
                $attrCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
                $value = $child->getDataUsingMethod($attrCode) ?: $child->getData($attrCode);
                if (null !== $value && $attrCode != 'entity_id') {
                    $attributes[$attrCode] = $value;
                }
            }

            $attributes['store_id'] = $child->getStoreId();
            $attributes['id'] = $child->getId();
            /**
             * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $productDataObject
             */
            $productDataObject = $this->productFactory->create();
            $this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray(
                $productDataObject,
                $attributes,
                '\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface'
            );
            $childrenList[] = $productDataObject;
        }
    }

    $childConfigData = array();
    foreach($childrenList as $child){
        $childConfigData[] = $child;
    }

    return $childConfigData;
}

public function getCurrentStoreId()
{
    return $this->storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId();
}

public function log($info)
{
    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . $this->logFilePath);
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->info($info);
}
```

Comment: tried to override "Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\ConfigurablePriceResolver" and make the chages to get the highest price.. after changes its working.. but when i select option all the price showing as 0 except the highest price associated product.

Comment: maybe show us the code?

Comment: @SUBINCHANDRAN did you got the solution??? i am also looking for the same>

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the return ***(float)*** $price in the aroundResolvePrice function to solve the price = 0 issue